# Access properties of Flat File Destination in SSIS via Script

Tags: scripting, ssis, flat-file

I have a Data Flow task that has a Flat File Destination in it.  The 'Overwrite' property is set to False by default.  I have a project parameter (boolean) that I need to check and if it is true then I need to set the Flat File Destination Overwrite property to true.

I have a script that checks my parameter but I can not find the "path" to take to get to the variable I need to change:

```
public void Main()
{

     if (Convert.ToBoolean(Dts.Variables["$Package::IsMonthly"].Value)==true)
         {SET OVERWRITE PROPERTY TO TRUE}
     Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Can someone help me with the correct variable/path for this?

Thanks,
Leslie

Answer (score 0):

You should use an expression on the Flat File Destination that checks whether the parameter is true/false and use that to overwrite the default value of that property

Comment: Ok I would be willing to do that but I don't see an EXPRESSIONS on the Data Flow Component Flat File Destination and the property is normally accessed through a check box in the UI.  I would still need to know the script to change that property, right?